# Decrypt the email id in php and update the database table by matching the email id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to decrypt my email id in php and i have brought encrypted email id from    json. I have to update the database table by matching this decrypted email id in  database.But m not able to update it from decrypted email id.After decryption am getting  the right email id.But not able to update the database table.

```
     `code here`

           $decryptEmail=null;
           $email = $this->_request['a'];
      $password = $this->_request['b']; 
      if($email!="")
      {
      $mcrypt = new MCrypt();
      $decrypted = $mcrypt->decrypt($email);
      $decryptEmail = utf8_decode(urldecode($decrypted));
      }
      if($decryptEmail=="")
      {
      echo 'empty';
      }
      else
           {
      echo $decryptEmail;
      $result = mysql_query("UPDATE usertable SET LoginStatus='t where substr     (EmailID,1,length(trim(EmailID)))=substr('$decryptEmail',1,length(trim('$decryptEmail')))") or die('Errant query:'. mysql_error());

           if (!$result) 
      {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
       }
            else
            {
       echo 'Verified successfully.';
        }
    MYSQL_CLOSE();
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: ok is there any specfic encrytion u want ? what is error i getting?

Comment: Your query is whack, whats `LoginStatus='t where`?

Comment: Login status is just the field of the table that i have to update. passing decrypted email id

Comment: M not getting any error its jst that m not able to update the database table.coz decrypted email id is npt matched with the original one

Comment: why are you using substr ?

Comment: removing substr function den also issue remains the same.i have tried that also

Comment: try changing query to this: $result = mysql_query("UPDATE usertable SET LoginStatus='t' where EmailID='{$decryptEmail}'");

Comment: braces which you have put in the query...This error is coming Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'abc@gmail.com' at line 1